# Optimization-Cost function

Tags: optimization

I consider the cost function given by
$$ TC=q_1 +kq_2  
$$
$
 k\in(0,1).
$
Demand functions are given by 
$

$$
q_1(p_1,p_2)=q_2(p_1,p_2)=(p_1p_2)^{-3},  p_1>0, p_2>0
$$
I need to find optimal values for prices and find the values of k for which one of the products is priced under marginal cost.

The answer is $$ p_1=p_2=3/5(1+k), 
             k>3/2 $$
When I rewrite TC as $$ TC=(k+1){{(p_1p_2)}^{-3}} $$ 
I find the FOC(first-order conditions):
$$ \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial TC}{\partial p_1},  \frac{\partial TC}{\partial p_2}
\end{equation}$$ which is unhelpful for finding critical points
$p_1, p_2$ and that's why I can't proceed to finding definiteness of Hessian.
Thanks for Your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The optimal prices are those which maximise *total profit*, so the first-order optimality conditions are not
$$
 \frac{\partial TC}{\partial p_1}=  \frac{\partial TC}{\partial p_2}=0\ ,
$$
but
$$
 \frac{\partial TP}{\partial p_1}=  \frac{\partial TP}{\partial p_2}=0\ ,
$$
where
\begin{eqnarray}
TP &=& p_1q_1 + p_2q_2 - q_1 - kq_2\\
&=& \frac{1}{p_1^2p_2^3} + \frac{1}{p_1^3p_2^2}-\frac{1+k}{p_1^3p_2^3}
\end{eqnarray}